# Make a custom time format in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-2013

How can I create a custom time format?

I'm using a Excel sheet to track my work hours. And I add up the work hours for each day and get a week total. But it seems it cant display above 24:00.  unless I change the format to hh:mm:ss.

I don't want the extra 2 digits at the end but the only other option is hh:mm.#

I want it to be hh:mm but display more than 24 hrs (like 36:50).

I also don't understand the "custom" option  can someone help?

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
[hh]:mm
```

As your custom format

[image]

Comment: Thank you!  sorry, the last time i ever touched excel was a couple years ago in one of my highschool's business classes